# How to copy ABC file material to another?

Tags: materials

I have a imported ABC model and I selected faces and assigned three materials on it. Now I have another ABC file with same mesh but different anim data
[image]

[image]

How to copy materials to the left one without assign them individually ??
I tried Ctrl + L to copy material or object data, only the first material is assigned

[image]

Comment: Im pretty sure this question is clear enough to not be a duplicate. And I'm also almost sure, that the most common problem to this abc import is to import each part (which needs a unique material) as a separate abc.

Comment: I wish my partner could separate them as well, but he made the clothes in MD and seems like they are inseparable , I'm thinking they all share same UV map maybe there's way to do it...